# ShadowDOMV0 behavior with Polyfill with --disabled-blink-features flag

Tags: google-chrome, polymer-1.0, web-component, shadow-dom, shady-dom

As per Polymer [blog](https://www.polymer-project.org/blog/2018-10-02-webcomponents-v0-deprecations.html), Chrome will deprecate `WebComponents v0` from march 2019.
My app is built with `Polymer v1.x` and we are using native `ShadowDOM`. After deprecation, `ShadowDOM` will no longer work and implementation will fall back to Shady DOM. As per blog, sites based on Polymer v1.x can use Polyfills to solve the issues caused by these upcoming deprecations.

Just wanted to confirm if Polyfill also works for ShadowDOM? Or, does it require manual conversion of shadowDOM api(s) to ShadyDOM?

Comment: Can you try the `disable-blink-features` flag to see if the polyfill works?

Comment: I already tried with Polyfill but my app crashes for shadow dom , showing error on shadow dom api(s).